# Mongodb multi type field

Tags: string, mongodb, indexing, integer, database

I need to index a field that may store strings/ numbers(int or float) or arrays.

I've indexed it using ({ field:1}) but some of the content is large an I get the "key too large to index" error.

What if I will index it using text index, should it solve my problem? Will it index numbers as well?

Is there a way to create multiple indexes for a single field (numbers and strings) that support large content?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Mongodb, The [Index Key Limit](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Index-Key-Limit) is less than 1024 bytes, you can change your index to [text index](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-text-index-on-multiple-fields/) or [hashed index](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-hashed-index/).

However the text index on the field or fields whose value is a *string* or an *array of string elements*, so in your case, it is better to use hashed index

```
db.collection.createIndex( { field: "hashed" } )
```

---

BTW, maybe there is another way to start mongodb as below with [`failIndexKeyTooLong` as false](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/parameters/#param.failIndexKeyTooLong) to disable the index key limit.

```
sudo mongod --setParameter failIndexKeyTooLong=false
```

Comment: The problem is that I have a lot of regex queries. Is hashed index can handle it properly?

Comment: @user2288183, IMO, per those infor from doc, `If an index exists for the field, then MongoDB matches the regular expression against the values in the index, which can be faster than a collection scan. Further optimization can occur if the regular expression is a “prefix expression”, which means that all potential matches start with the same string. This allows MongoDB to construct a “range” from that prefix and only match against those values from the index that fall within that range.` The hashed index could handle it well.

Comment: @user2288183, maybe you could compare them through comparing.